# Linker causing seemingly random crashes?

Tags: c++, linker, crash, stack

EDIT: After some more trying and testing, it seems to set down to changing stack size everytime I change code and I want the program to run. If I don't change the stack size, the program seems to crash everytime after code change.

EDIT 2: Same seems to apply to both `/HEAP` and `/STACK`

A bit of and odd question, but as far as I can tell, based on some checking and testing.

On multiple projects (at some point) I've come across this same problem:

I change a bit of code, the program crashes.
I change stack size, the program doesn't crash(with the changed code), doesn't seem to matter if incrementing or decrementing stack size.

Seemingly as if there's a hidden randomized stack which, if below a certain value causing the program to crash (no error). I can cause the crash by testing different stack sizes.

On a recent project, the crash seems to "pinpoint" to the bit of code:

```
typedef unsigned int DINT;

template <typename LIST_ITEM>
struct LIST {
    LIST() {
        this->length = 0;
        this->total = 0;
        for (DINT i = 0; i < ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX; i++) {
            //this->item[i] = { 0 };
            this->existance[i] = 0;
        }
    };
    ~LIST() {

        for (DINT i = 0; i < ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX; i++) {
            //this->item[i] = { 0 };
            this->existance[i] = 0;
        }
        this->length = 0;
        this->total = 0;
    };

    DINT length, total;
    LIST_ITEM item[ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX];
    DINT existance[ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX];
    DINT _set(LIST_ITEM item) {
        for (DINT d = 0; d < ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX; d++) {
            if (this->existance[d] == 0) {
                this->item[d] = item;
                this->existance[d] = 1;
                this->length++;
                this->total++;
                return d;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void _remove(DINT position = 0) {
        this->item[position] = {};
        this->existance[position] = 0;

        
        LIST <LIST_ITEM> list = {};
        DINT length = 0;
        do {
            if (this->existance[length] == 1) {
                list._set(this->_get(length));
                this->existance[length] = 0;
                //this->item[l] = {};
            }
            length++;
        } while (length < ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX);
        this->_carry(list);
    }

    LIST_ITEM _get(DINT position = 0) {
        return this->item[position];
    }

    void _carry(LIST <LIST_ITEM> list = {}) {
        for (DINT d = 0; d < list.length; d++) {
            if (list.existance[d] == 1) this->_set(list.item[d]);
        }
    }

    void _deconstruct() {
        /*
        for (DINT i = 0; i < ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX; i++) {
            if (this->existance[i] == 1) {
                this->existance[i] = 0;
                this->item[i] = { };
            }
        }
        this->length = 0;
        this->total = 0;
        */
        this->~LIST();
    }
};
```

Possible solution/fix:

```
    void _remove(DINT position = 0) {
        this->existance[position] = 0;
        this->length--;
        LIST <LIST_ITEM> *list = new LIST;
        for (DINT a = 0; a < ENGINE_DATABASE_LIST_LENGTH_MAX; a++) {
            if (this->existance[a] == 1) {
                list->_set(this->item[a]);
                if (list->length == this->length) break;
            }
        }
        list->total = this->total;
        *this = *list;
        delete list;
    }
```

If the max list length is set to 64, the program seems to run fine, no matter of stack, but at 128 the crashes start to happen, and if I do the above (change stack size by even just 1, the program runs fine again, until next change of code, then I change stack by 1 again and the program runs fine again).

There might be a "< 0" somewhere (which could also cause crashing), which I just can't seem to spot.

Please do point out.

Seem confusing? Please ask.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] for us so we can reproduce the issue? For all we know, you could have UB somewhere. If you can't make a minimal example, try ASAN/UBSAN/Valgrind/...

Comment: If changing the stack size (something which you should never have to do really) changes the behavior, then it's very likely you have a bug in your code where you do something that leads to probable out-of-bounds indexing, and on to undefined behavior.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need a destructor in your `LIST` class.  After an object is destructed you should not access its member variables, so "resetting" them is kind of pointless.

Comment: On a possible related note, you pass many arguments *by value* meaning that copies are created. These copies will be placed om the stack, and could lead to worsen behavior if your stack is trained to begin with. For structures, especially larger ones like your `LIST`, make it a habit to pass by (preferably constant) reference instead.

Comment: Also, explicitly calling the destructor `this->~LIST();` while technically allowed under some circumstances, is *extremely* unusual. Seems out of place here.

Comment: Furthermore, in your `_get` function you have no bounds-checking. And in your `_set` function, how do you differ between actually setting index `0` and a full "list" when you return `0`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do you mean actually setting? The return 0 is if it cannot find a ```existance == 0```. I haven't actually filled any list yet (haven't gotten as far yet).

Also, thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: In the `_set` function, if `this->existance[0] == 0` is true, you "set" the element at index `0`. Then you return `0` (as `d == 0`). But you also return `0` if there is no free elements, and the loop runs to its end. How do you differ from `_get` returning `0` because you have set the element at index `0`, or because the "list" is full and you return `0`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It just returns the position in the "array" where it found an "empty" position, although if there are no "elements", then 0 likely to cause crashing, but the crashing happens while it has something in it, 0 position has value. 

You mean I should change to ```signed int```(s) for ```-1``` error checking?

Also, I'm still curious why stack acts as if it needs to be different everytime I change code, for the program to not crash.

Comment: A common pattern would be to return `reinterpret_cast<DINT>(-1)`, and check for that.

Comment: And if you want any kind of debugging help, then please tell us what efforts of debugging you have tried yourself (besides changing stack size), how it worked (or not worked), and of course show us a proper [mre]. Besides the lack of bounds-checking in `_get` there's really nothing directly wrong with the code you show. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Appreciate the comments, and my gut tells me it's gotta be the ```-1``` error-checking-out-of-bounds somewhere. As far as I can tell, the only reoccurring pattern seems to be the stack changing.

Comment: Because you have only posted partial code it's very likely your undefined behaviour is in the code you haven't posted. Under what circumstances do you call `_deconstruct()` for example?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb None, it was used at some point, but became obsolete for now, replaced by other code.

Comment: So you posted some code you don't use and would like us to guess where in the code you haven't posted there might be an error? Your chances of finding an answer that way are slim. Perhaps check the unshown code for the template parameter type LIST_ITEM that it follows the rule of 3 since you're passing everything using value semantics.

Comment: Appreciate all of the comments, for what it's worth, defining the recursive LIST (in the object function) as new seemed to work.